# KotlinJs : how to write HandleBarJS in kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin, handlebars.js, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a running JS code that uses HandleBarJs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
let template = fs.readFileSync('template.txt', 'utf8')
let submissionJson = fs.readFileSync('submission.json', 'utf8')

var handleBarJs = require('handlebars');
handleBarJs.registerHelper('eq', function (firstParam, secondParam, options) {
    if (firstParam == secondParam) return options.fn(this); else return options.inverse(this);
})
handleBarJs.registerHelper('contains', function (firstParam, secondParam, options) {
    if (firstParam.includes(secondParam)) return options.fn(this); else return options.inverse(this);
})
var compiledTemplate = handleBarJs.compile(template)
var output = compiledTemplate(JSON.parse(submissionJson));
console.log(output);
```

I want to write same code in Kotlin JS. This is what I tried:

```
actual class HandleBarService actual constructor() {

    private val handleBars = require("handlebars")

    actual fun generateCertificateString(template: String, data: Any): String {

        println("Input Template:\n$template")
//        println("Input Json:\n${data}")

        val eqHelper = lambda@ fun(firstParam: String, secondParam: String, options: dynamic) {
            println("firstParam: $firstParam secondParam: $secondParam")
            if (firstParam == secondParam) return options.fn(lambda@ this) else return options.inverse(lambda@ this)
        }
        val containsHelper = lambda@ fun(firstParam: List<String>, secondParam: String, options: dynamic) {
            if (firstParam.contains(secondParam)) return options.fn(lambda@ this) else return options.inverse(lambda@ this)
        }

        handleBars.registerHelper("eq", eqHelper)
        handleBars.registerHelper("contains", containsHelper)

        val handlebarTemplate = handleBars.compile(template)
        val dataTemplate = handlebarTemplate(data)
        println("HandleBar Output:\n$dataTemplate")
        return dataTemplate
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<b>List Of Violations For </b>
<br></br>
{{#each modules}}
    {{#eq type 'checklist' }}
        {{#each data.checklistItemResults}}
            {{#contains violation.finalActions 'order'}}
                <br><b>Requirement:</b></br>
                <br> {{checklistItemDescription}} </br>
                <br><b>Violation:</b></br>
                <br>{{violation.description}}</br>
                <br><b>CorrectiveActions:</b></br>
                <br>{{#each violation.correctiveActions}} {{this}} {{/each}}</br>
            {{/contains}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/eq}}
{{/each}}
```

Json:

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "data": {
        "checklistItemResults": [
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "Failed to properly register all regulated tanks with the Department.",
              "type": "Major",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Submit a completed Underground Storage Tank Facility Certification Questionnaire: on the effective date of this document."
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "Failed to make the Registration Certificate available.",
              "type": "Major",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Make registration certificate available."
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "Failed to submit an amended UST Questionnaire to reflect changes in status made to the UST systems.  Specifically, (provide details)",
              "type": "Minor",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Submit a completed Underground Storage Tank Facility Certification Questionnaire: within 30 days of receipt of this document."
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "Failed to have Financial Responsibility Assurance Mechanism as required.",
              "type": "Major",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Immediately obtain Financial Responsibility as required."
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "The owner and operator failed to maintain records of operation and maintenance walkthrough inspections for five years. ",
              "type": "Minor",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Comply with rule\/regulation: within 30 days of receipt of this document."
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "checklistItemDescription": "",
            "violation": {
              "description": "Release Response Plan not available for the inspection.",
              "type": "Minor",
              "correctiveActions": [
                "Make Release Response Plan available."
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "type": "checklist"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
<b>List Of Violations For </b>
<br></br>
                <br><b>Requirement:</b></br>
                <br> Any person that owns or operates an underground storage tank system shall register each tank system with the Department. [N.J.A.C. 7:14B- 2.1(a)] </br>
                <br><b>Violation:</b></br>
                <br>Failed to properly register all regulated tanks with the Department.</br>
                <br><b>CorrectiveActions:</b></br>
                <br> Submit a completed Underground Storage Tank Facility Certification Questionnaire: on the effective date of this document. </br>
                <br><b>Requirement:</b></br>
                <br> In accordance with N.J.A.C. 7:14B-5.6(b), the owner and operator shall maintain records of operation and maintenance walkthrough inspections for five years. The record shall identify the areas checked, whether each area checked was acceptable or required corrective action, a description of any corrective action taken, and delivery records if spill prevention equipment is checked less than every 30 days due to infrequent deliveries. [N.J.A.C. 7:14B- 5.12(c)] </br>
                <br><b>Violation:</b></br>
                <br>The owner and operator failed to maintain records of operation and maintenance walkthrough inspections for five years. </br>
                <br><b>CorrectiveActions:</b></br>
                <br> Comply with rule/regulation: within 30 days of receipt of this document. </br>
                <br><b>Requirement:</b></br>
                <br> No person shall operate (nor cause to be operated) a significant source or control apparatus serving the significant source without a valid operating certificate. [N.J.A.C. 7:27- 8.3(b)] </br>
                <br><b>Violation:</b></br>
                <br>Release Response Plan not available for the inspection.</br>
                <br><b>CorrectiveActions:</b></br>
                <br> Make Release Response Plan available. </br>
```

Actual Output:

```
<b>List Of Violations For </b>
<br></br>
```

I am getting desired output with pure JS code but not with Kotlin JS, can someone help with it?

I think problem is with registering Helpers. Not sure how would we write `this` keyword inside lambda to not point `HandleBarService`
Also, I went through [this expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) documentation

Comment: Can you tell us what happens?

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson I have edited the question. Can you check again?